# Make footer stretch bottom of page without using body tag

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla2.5

I have been researching this for hours now trying different solutions but none of them have seemed to work for me, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it is the template I am using. I have tried the cssstickyfooter and that has not worked for me either.

I have already got a background image set within pages so I can't use the solution of setting the body tag with a background colour. The debug div needs to stretch all the way to the bottom of the page. I have zoomed out using chrome and it is not doing this.

Here is the css code:

```
#rt-debug {
   background-color: #BF953F;
   padding-bottom: 15px;
   border-top: 4px solid #2A9685;
}
```

I added the a footer2 div around the debug to test the cssstickyfooter solution

Here is the link to the website:
http://www.humanenergygroup.com/oil-and-gas-uk

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is add the following to your #rt-debug div:

```
#rt-debug {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will ensure that it is always full page width as well as keeping it "sticky" to the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit of a hack, but you can use jQuery like this:

```
var t = $("#rt-debug").offset().top;
var ih = window.innerHeight;
$("#rt-debug").css('height',ih-t + "px");
```

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tLNCW/